# How to return default value from PL/SQL procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I just want to know is there any functionality in Oracle to return default values from a procedure or a function? I know that we can pass default values to a procedure.

Comment: What purpose would it serve? Instead use a default value directly wherever you need. But, if you really need a PL/SQL code to return a default value, then declare a constant variable and return it.

Comment: Compatibility with oldest versions!

Answer (score 1):

No.

A **default value** cannot be assigned to the `OUT` parameter. An OUT parameter is a **pass by value** method. The parameter must be assigned with a value within the subprogram body. This value is then passed to the host environment, from where the subprogram has been called.

In a function, the value to be returned must be within the body.

I suggest you could **declare a constant**, and then use it either as OUT parameter in a procedure or RETURN it in a function.

Comment: maybe he is asking for a view like let's name it dba_procedures_default_values. I think he just want to find what is the default values of procedures/functions.